# PHP ternary !empty rather than evaluates to true or false

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Is it possible to use the shorthand ternary to check whether a variable is set or not instead of whether is evaluates to zero or non-zero?

For example, I tried:

```
$var = 0;
echo (string) $var ?: (string) false ?: 2;
```

But since both the first two expressions evaluate to "0" or "false", 2 is displayed.

I thought that perhaps casting them to a string would produce different results, but it did not.  Zero is zero I suppose.

I'm wanting to use this style when assigning variables such as

```
$get->var = $get->var ?: $setindb ?: $default;
```

I want to assign $get->var to $get->var if it is set, otherwise, check if the db has a value, otherwise, use a default.

## Edit

I thought I would mention that I know I could do something like

```
$get->var = (!empty($get->var)) ? $get->var : ( (!empty($setindb)) ? $setindb : $default )
```

But you be the judge at which is simpler :)

Comment: why don't you use isset($get->var) instead?

Comment: well, instead of empty, in my example above, isset would be more appropriate, but that still puts me in the same situation.  I was looking for a cleaner simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string "0" and "false" are considered `FALSE`-y ([list of false values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) values in PHP.

`isset()` returns `TRUE` for variables that are set and not `NULL`. `empty()` will check that the variable is set and that is isn't a `FALSE` value. So it would return `TRUE` for "0".

I think that what you want is your third code snippet, but with `isset()`, rather than `empty()`.

The easiest way to do (with the least amount of brackets) that would be:

```
$get->var = isset($get->var) ? $get->var : (isset($setindb) ? $setindb : $default);
```

Since the shorthand tenary returns the first parameter, you can't use it, because that would be a boolean. ( `isset($get->var) ?: $default` would return `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `$default`, but never `$get->var`'s value. )

---

Edit: Perhaps you'd like something like a coalesce function? PHP doesn't offer it natively, as far as I know, but it's trivial to create. Note that this might be a bit ugly, due to its use of passing references to a function. I'd be interested in comments on this (is it as bad as I think it is?).

```
function coalesce(array $values)
{
    foreach($values as &$value)
    {
        if(isset($value))
            return $value;
    }
    return null;
}
$this->var = coalesce(array(&$this->var, &$setindb, $default));
```

I haven't tested the above. Pass variables in the array as references (`&` symbol). I'm pretty sure it'll choke on something like `coalesce(array(1,"a_string",false));`.

Comment: okay, didn't know if there was some trick (like casting) that a ternary will check other than true or false

Comment: PHP7 has a coalesce operator implemented with ?? http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op